How to access Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing namespace
I need to use IOutboundParameterTransformer which is contained in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing. However I can't manage to get that namespace to work.
I've added a framework reference like so
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
  <ItemGroup>
      <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

However then I get a The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref' was not recognized error and I still can't access the namespace.

It is just Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, not Ref:
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

See the Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework section of the docs.
